# How to return custom content on HttpException in EmbedIO?

Tags: c#, http, embedio

I have an EmbedIO API and want to return an HttpException, like for example "401 - unauthorized". If a username is not found upon logging in, I throw an HttpException inside my API endpoint method, like the following:

```
// return 401
throw HttpException.Unauthorized(message="user name does not exist", data=myData);
```

But it seems like EmbedIO ignores the data, which I thought would be included in my response content. But instead I get a "standard" response, generated by the server that only uses my message and says:

> ﻿401 -
> Unauthorized
>
> ## 401 -
> Unauthorized
>
> **Exception type:**
> EmbedIO.HttpException
>
> **Message:** user name does not
> exist
>
> ---
>
> If this error is completely unexpected to you, and you
> think you should not seeing this page, please contact the server
> administrator, informing them of the time this error occurred and the
> action(s) you performed that resulted in this error.

Does anybody know how to return a response with custom content that is specified throught the "data" parameter? Like for example

{
"userName" : "testUser",
"userNameExist" : "false",
"attempt" : 5
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the response with the `HandleHttpException` method:

```
var server = new WebServer(8877);

server.HandleHttpException(async (context, exception) =>
{
    context.Response.StatusCode = exception.StatusCode;

    switch (exception.StatusCode)
    {
        case 401:
            await context.SendDataAsync(new { userName = "testUser", userNameExist = false, attempt = 5 });
            break;
        default:
            await HttpExceptionHandler.Default(context, exception);
            break;
    }
});`
```

Look here: https://unosquare.github.io/embedio/wiki/Cookbook.html#setting-a-custom-error-page